# Type Mismatch when using CreateControl in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to dynamically create controls on a form as needed and I have therefore used the CreateControl Method.

```
DateControls(i) = CreateControl(Reports!Comments_R, acTextBox, acDetail, , , TopValue, 0, 5400, 1440)
```

In the following line of code above, when I try to compile the project "CreateControl" is highlighted and a popup box indicates that there is a type mismatch. DateControl is declared as a Control. I have also tried declaring it as a Variant and I still receive the same error. Another time I tried it without using an array and again, still the same error. Any ideas as to what could be wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: You mention `DateControl` but your code says `DateControls`. Do you have `Option Explicit` at the top of your VBA Module? If not, you should put it there.

Comment: Yes, I do have Option Explicit and the variable is spelled correctly in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type mismatch is on the the first argument to CreateControl. It must be a String. This will get you past the type mismatch error:

```
    CreateControl(Reports!Comments_R.Name, ...
```

However, you have two other problems.

- Since a control is an object, you need to use `Set` in your
  assignment statement.
- It looks like you want to add the control to a
  Report. If so, use CreateReportControl instead.